# What is the largest value of a Poisson random variable with mean 1

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I know that a Poisson random variable (say with mean 1) is a discrete random variable that takes values on all non negative integers.  I am curious to know what is the largest integer Mma could return under the command:

RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[1]]

Comment: Realistically, it won't be very large `SeedRandom[1234]; Max@RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[1], 1000000]` evaluates to `9`

Comment: Yes, Thank you.  I saw the integer 12 once using essentially the same code.  This is what made me curious to know the absolute maximum integer that Mma can return

Comment: Obviously the theoretical answer is going to be "any positive integer", but practically those will be extremely unlikely, as you said yourself. You can certainly run the same test mentioned by @Bob above. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Yes, I want to know what the largest integer that Mma could actually return for the command.

Comment: The largest integer would result from something like a cosmic ray flipping a bit in a register during the calculation. This is far more probable than a result >20.

Comment: Disregarding cases involving outside interference from cosmic rays, are you saying that it is possible that Mma could return a value > 20.  Maybe it depends on what kind of computer I have?  Isn't there some point  in the algorithm where Mma would stop computing and automatically return some maximum value?

Comment: It depends on the algorithm that *Mathematica* uses to generate random samples from a Poisson and how one samples.  One could certainly consider a sample size of 10^160 and break the Poisson distribution into 2 parts:  say numbers below 100 and numbers 100 and above.  First choose a random sample from a binomial with sample size 10^6 and probability `1 - PDF[PoissonDistribution[1], 99]`.  That gets you the sample size to sample from a truncated Poisson distribution (with the truncation being all values from 100 to $\infty$).  So you'll get values greater than 99.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of the pudding  is in the eating. Here are the results on my comp.

```
Max[RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[1], 2*10^8]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{86.0863, 12}`

```
Table[1 - CDF[PoissonDistribution[1], k], {k, 10, 13}] // N
```

> `{1.00478*10^-8, 8.31611*10^-10, 6.35977*10^-11, 4.51983*10^-12}`

```
Max[RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[1], 10^9]]
```

crashes my comp.

Comment: `SeedRandom[15]; Max[RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[1], 10^9]]` gives 13.